# java Array sorting inside a method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I have to complete a school assignment which is based on a battle simulation game.Can your review my guild class code, i have some issues with the sort functionality.It works without it too but i still want to implement it. The get members method should sort the array based on lvl of the players and then use this array to form the team of members

this guild class

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public  class Guild {
    ArrayList<Character> memebers;

    public Guild() {
        memebers = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addMember(Character member){
        memebers.add(member);
    }

    public Collection<Character> getMembers(){
        return (Collection<Character>)memebers;
    }

    public StudentTeam getTeam(Team enemyTeam){

        StudentTeam team = new StudentTeam("StudentTeam");

        **memebers.sort(new Comparator<Character>(){
            public int compare(Character c1, Character c2) {
                if (c1.getLevel() > c2.getLevel()){
                    return 1;
                }else if (c1.getLevel() < c2.getLevel()){
                    return  -1;
                }else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });**

        for (Character member : memebers){
            team.addMember(member);
            member.setTeam(team);
        }

        return team;
    }


} ``
```

Comment: Do you have a class named `Character`? There is already a Java `Character` class.

Comment: yes i do have a class named Character

Comment: So what is the issue you are having?

Comment: it does not do what is supposed to, when I run it the result is the same as if it was no there

Comment: I tried to use this approach because I find it to be more convenient, provided that everything happens within that method

Comment: I don't see a problem. The `memebers` array list should be sorted. Note: you can simplify the comparator as: `public int compare(Character c1, Character c2) { return c1.getLevel() - c2.getLevel(); }` Assuming `getLevel()` returns a numeric value.

Comment: thanks a lot, just wondering is there any way contact you, I have other questions as well and it would take to long for someone to answer each one of them>

Comment: Good questions actually get answered pretty quickly here. This question did not because it was not clear what you were asking.